# Installing libao with luarocks expects different Lua version

Tags: lua, luarocks

I installed **Lua** and **libao** via Homebrew on my mac (10.12 sierra) and **ao** via luarocks.
Now when I try to run the [ao_example.lua](http://github.com/TheLinx/lao/raw/master/src/ao_example.lua) file I get the following error:

> lua: error loading module 'ao' from file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/ao.so':
>       dlopen(/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/ao.so, 6): Symbol not found: _luaL_register
>     Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/ao.so
>     Expected in: flat namespace
>    in /usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/ao.so

As far as I understand ao from luarocks expects Lua Version 5.1 whereas I have 5.2 installed.

I'm very unexperienced with Lua and have no idea how to solve this problem.